# UWP C# - listview change "item" background color depending of value (not the entire row)

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

The following code run when loading rows to listview  what happens only once.
My ListView items only have 2 values - "x" and "n". I want the item("cell") with value "x" to have as background color Red.
The following code has 2 issues for me:
1) I do not want to specify all columns/items (goodFH, Position, etc) to have the "cell" Red if value = "x" (would like as pseudocode "if current cell value = "x" then Red")
2) args.ItemContainer.Background change the entire row background and not the "cell" I wish!

```
private void listViewContentChange(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {

        if (((Binding.Car)args.Item).GoodFH == "x")
        {
            args.ItemContainer.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["Red"];
        }
        else
        {
            if (((Binding.Car)args.Item).Position == "x")
            {
                args.ItemContainer.Background =(SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["red"];

            }
        }
    }


<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Car">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind GoodFH}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="158"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind Position }" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind PathFHfs}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind PathBHFlSp }" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
```

Any Help? Hope the question is understandable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I known, we can not change the Background of the `cell` by setting the `ItemContainer.Background`.

We should be able to set the `TextBlock` in the Grid that we can change the Background of the Grid.

Also we can use the bind to set the `Background` of the Grid. To bind the "GoodFH" to the `Background`, we should be able to use the [`IValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

For example:

The MyValueConverters.cs code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (value.ToString() == "x")
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return value;
}
```

The XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyValueConverters x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView  Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}" ContainerContentChanging="listViewContentChange">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                        <Grid Background="{x:Bind GoodFH,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock  FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind GoodFH}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="158"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Background="{x:Bind Position,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind Position }" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind PathFHfs}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind PathBHFlSp }" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thks Jayden. Your solution is perfect for me!